# Determining Subspaces, Boundedness and Calculation of Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am studying real analysis  and came up to this question:

Let $S : \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ such that $ S (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (0, a_2, 0,... , 0, a_{2n}, 0,...) $. Prove that $S$ is bounded, calculate its norm and the subspaces $\operatorname{Im}S$ and $\operatorname{Ker}S$.

I presume that the following are correct:

A function is bounded if there exists a constant $c$ such that $ |S(x)| \leq c \cdot |x| $ for all $x$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. In this case, we can see that the output of $S$ is always less than or equal to the input, hence $S$ is bounded.

The $\operatorname{Im}S$ is the set of all vectors that can be written as $S(x)$ for some $x$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. In this case, $\operatorname{Im}S$ consists of sequences that have non-zero elements at even indices only.
The $\operatorname{Ker}S$ is the set of all vectors $x$ in $ \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) $ such that $S(x) = 0$. In this case, $\operatorname{Ker}S$ consists of sequences that have non-zero elements at odd indices only.

But I don't know how to proceed from here, I got a recommendation from my professor to use sum. Also can someone edit the latex in this, I cant get it right.

Comment: Your description of the image and kernel are fine; is it just showing that the function is bounded and finding the norm? If so, you might find that writing out expressions for $|S(x)|$ and $|x|$ is useful. You should find that $S$ has norm 1.